# combining a WHERE and IN clause with two fields

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I have a table 'goods' with 3 columns (id, name, price). I need to get data by list of ids and price range.

I'm using this query:

```
SELECT id, name, price FROM goods
WHERE (id, price)
IN ((1,10), (3,20), (2,10))
ORDER BY FIELD(id, 1,3,2)
```

Everything is just fine while I'm using strict price values.

In fact, I need to do query like:

```
SELECT id, name, price FROM goods
WHERE (id, price)
IN ((1, BETWEEN 0 AND 100), (2, BETWEEN 50 AND 150), (n, BETWEEN m AND k))
ORDER BY FIELD(id, 1,3,n)
```

I found expression `(1, BETWEEN 0 AND 100)` will never return the result I need, while `(1,10)`  will.

I'm surely can exclude records by price range in php, but I'm trying to find more efficient way to do it in mysql query using indexes. What should I do?

Answer (score 4):

You can't use BETWEEN like that. Try changing your IN expression to a series of ORs instead:

```
SELECT id, name, price
FROM goods
WHERE
    (id = 1 AND price BETWEEN 0 AND 100) OR
    (id = 2 AND price BETWEEN 50 AND 150) OR
    (id = n AND price BETWEEN m AND k)
ORDER BY FIELD(id, 1,3, n)
```

Comment: I need to use from 1 to 50 coditions like `(id = 1 AND price BETWEEN 0 AND 100)` - will it increase query time a lot (even using index on fields `id, price`)?

Comment: *Will it increase query time a lot*... increase compared to what?

Comment: I mean using 50 direct conditions like `(id = 1)` seems slower than `id IN (1,..,50)` to me (even without price range). Am I wrong?